# Why not having /tmp default permissions to 777 in osX?

Tags: macos, permissions, symbolic-link

I'm often using, on unix servers I'm working with, the /tmp folder as a folder where I write temporal stuff needed for my software (mainly web applications). It has usually 777 permissions.

I found in my local machine, which mounts OsX Maverick, that the /tmp folder does NOT have 777 permissions, but `drwxr-xr-x`.

/tmp is actually a symbolic link to /private/tmp, which has the same permissions.

My question is: is there any security reason why /tmp (or /private/tmp) should not have 777 permissions? Practical explanatory examples would be great!

Comment: `/tmp` with mode 0777 wouldn't be very nice on a multi-user system; it means anyone can delete anyone else's temporary files. You probably meant **1777**, which is world writable with the sticky bit set, so any user can write but only the owner of a file can delete the file.

Comment: I think the key to answering your question is the `/private` part. What exactly is that used for in OS X?

Comment: In unix if you have write permissions on a folder, you can write or delete any file inside that folder. /private is a container for parts of the standard unix filesystem hierarchy that may vary between individual computers (e.g. /etc is a symlink to /private/etc, where the actual config files are). AIUI this was originally done to support netbooting under NextSTEP. Taken from: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63555/what-is-darwins-private-directory-for#63565

Comment: *"In unix if you have write permissions on a folder, you can write or delete any file inside that folder."* Unless the sticky bit is set on the directory. See for example http://superuser.com/a/153723/53590 as well as the other answers on that question.

Comment: Ok, good point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The /private/tmp/ directory should have permission modes 1777 (drwxrwxrwt) and not 0755 (drwxr-xr-x) as you are seeing.

Theses same modes (1777) should also be set on /var/tmp/

I can't speculate on the causes of your non-standard modes.

Comment: I agree with you. Still, with a fresh installation of Maverick, I had 0755.

Comment: On my 10.9.2 host the permissions are as follows:

`user@host:~ # ls -ld@ /tmp
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Oct 23  2013 /tmp -> private/tmp
 com.apple.FinderInfo 32 
user@host:~ # ls -ld@ /private/tmp
drwxrwxrwt  12 root  wheel  408 May 16 08:27 /private/tmp`

Comment: Fair enough!...

Comment: How come I can't change the permissions via sudo chmod?

Comment: @AlxVallejo, I will guess that you are trying to change the permission modes on a symbolic link. Unless you are using the '-h' option with chmod you will be changing the permission modes on the file or directory that the symbolic link points to rather than the link itself.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use this:

sudo diskutil repairPermissions /
- repairs permissions of system directories (like if /tmp is incorrect)

source: http://www.macworld.com/article/1052220/repairpermissions.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Although this may answer the question, you should give a more detailed description of the linked content and explain how it relates to the question. This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page goes is removed or goes offline. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).

Comment: This answer seems out of date for El Capitain as my diskutil has no repairPermissions action.